how to load pretrained iresnet100 model
Found these lines of code but they dont seem to work anymore, anyone knows what is the updated syntax to load iresnet100 model?
context is I am editing a existing python code that uses resnet50 pretrained model model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True).cuda(). I need to replace it with iresnet100 model
import insightface

embedder = insightface.iresnet100(pretrained=True)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 2
      1 import insightface
----> 2 embedder = insightface.iresnet100(pretrained=True)
      3 embedder.eval()

AttributeError: module 'insightface' has no attribute 'iresnet100'

import torch
from insightface.model_zoo import get_model

embedder = get_model('buffalo_s', pretrained=True).cuda()  # Use the appropriate model name
embedder.eval()  # Set the model to evaluation mode

tried these and it didnt work

contact the authors of https://pypi.org/project/insightface/
